# Precook or raw when chilling meat?

Tags: refrigerator, sausages, raw-meat

I currently have an unopened package of raw sausages in the fridge (with several days left before expiration).

I also have a recipe to use all of the sausages, but due to the other ingredients in the recipe (mostly pasta) I know I can't cook it all at once (due to pot size, mostly).  So I will have to make half of it at a time.

Is it better to pre-cook all the sausages and put half back in the fridge for a couple days until the second batch, or leave them raw?  And should I leave them in the original (now opened) packaging (if raw; I know I shouldn't do that if cooked) or transfer them to another container (which can be sealed)?

Comment: You may want to check: Does the container of the sausages specify that the best-before or use-by date applies to the unopened package? Does it indicate that it was packed with a special gas mixture, that would escape once you open the package? Do you have access to a freezer?

Comment: I don't think it's anything fancy; it's just bog-standard supermarket plastic wrap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either way should be ok for a couple of days.

Either keep them raw and cook them in a couple of days, or cook them now and re-heat them in a couple of days.

Comment: Agreed ... either will work.  Cooking first might be more convenient later (faster to throw something together on short notice), but there's typically better quality if you freeze it raw and cook as needed.

Comment: Ok.  Out of curiosity, does the answer change if it were "use by" today or tomorrow instead?  (Where the second batch won't be cooked before then.)

Comment: @Miral : the closer you are to the date, the better it would be to cook it in advance.  (as the time is cumulative, and you might decide to defrost in the fridge for a day or two)

Answer (score 0):

1. Precook all of them now.  Make them good; maybe parboil first then slice them and fry them or grill them to get that brown sausage goodness.
2. Freeze half because you won't want sausage again right away.
3. Warm up non frozen ones in the pasta water before you drain the pasta.
4. Next time you make pasta in a few weeks thaw your sliced frozen cooked sausage
   in the pasta water before you drain the pasta.

Everyone is happy!